# How to sort single object alphabetically?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to sort single object alphabetically...

maintaining its key and value both ex:

> **input is:** {2: "a", 3: "e", 4: "h", 5: "g", 6: "d", 7: "i", 8: "c", 9: "f", 10: "b"}
>
> **i need output:** {2: "a", 10: "b", 8: "c", 6: "d", 3: "e", 9: "f", 5: "g", 4: "h", 7: "i"}

here is my js code:

```
var myObject = {2: "a", 3: "e", 4: "h", 5: "g", 6: "d", 7: "i", 8: "c", 9: "f", 10: "b"}

keysSorted = Object.keys(myObject).sort(function(a,b){return myObject[a]-myObject[b]});
console.log(keysSorted);
```

here is my fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/j7yujL2y/

Comment: object property doesn't have any order..... what's the need of that?

Comment: @PranavCBalan actually my current project is like that only, i cant change the object.. i have to sort it like that only.

Answer (score 6):

If you just want to sort the property name array then use [`String#localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) for comparing string.

```js
var myObject = {
  2: "a",
  3: "e",
  4: "h",
  5: "g",
  6: "d",
  7: "i",
  8: "c",
  9: "f",
  10: "b"
}

keysSorted = Object.keys(myObject).sort(function(a, b) {
  return myObject[a].localeCompare(myObject[b])
});
console.log(keysSorted);
```

Comment: key is sorted perfectly but what about values :)

Comment: @AkshayKumar : you need to retrieve value based on the sorted key array...

Answer (score 1):

Objects are unordered maps, so you can't to get them ordered.
But, you can to get sorted keys and values separately.
It will be something like this:

```js
let myObject = {2: "Australia", 3: "China", 4: "Japan", 5: "Thailand", 6: "India", 7: "Malaysia", 8: "South Korea", 9: "Hong Kong", 10: "Taiwan", 11: "Philippines", 12: "Vietnam", 13: "France", 14: "United Kingdom", 15: "Germany", 16: "Sweden", 17: "Italy", 18: "Greece", 19: "Spain", 20: "Austria", 21: "The Netherlands", 22: "Belgium", 23: "Switzerland", 24: "United Arab Emirates", 26: "Ukraine", 27: "Russian Federation", 29: "Portugal", 30: "Saudi Arabia", 31: "Denmark", 33: "Norway", 34: "United States", 35: "Canada", 36: "Mexico", 38: "Poland", 39: "Czech Republic", 40: "Ireland", 41: "Bulgaria", 42: "Finland", 43: "Slovenia", 44: "Romania"}

let values = Object.keys(myObject).map(k => myObject[k]).sort();
let keys = Object.keys(myObject)
 .sort((a, b) => values.indexOf(myObject[a]) - values.indexOf(myObject[b]));

console.log(values, keys);
```

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/76346706/1772898

Answer (score 0):

Strange requirement.

You mean you need the output of console.log() look like what you write?
(I think it is impossible. :D)

In order to do this specific job, try create a new map with alpha as key and the number as value, although it doesn't look the same as you wish

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `Array` or `Map` of objects in a specific order

```js
var myObject = {
  2: "a",
  3: "e",
  4: "h",
  5: "g",
  6: "d",
  7: "i",
  8: "c",
  9: "f",
  10: "b"
};
const keys = Array.from({
  length: Object.keys(myObject).length
});
let order = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
let arr = [];
const map = new Map();
for (let key in myObject) {
  arr[order.indexOf(myObject[key])] = {
    [key]: myObject[key]
  };
}
for (let prop of arr) {
  map.set(prop[Object.keys(prop)], prop)
}
for (let prop of map) {
  console.log(prop)
}
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one:

```
var keysSorted = Object.keys(myObject).sort(function (a, b) {
    return myObject[a].localeCompare(myObject[b])
});
var SortedList = [];
keysSorted.forEach(function (value) {
    SortedList.push(myObject[value]);
});
```

Comment: @AkshayKumar you can use SortedList as ur output.

Answer (score 0):

```
 const myObject = {
  2: "a",
  3: "e",
  4: "h",
  5: "g",
  6: "d",
  7: "i",
  8: "c",
  9: "f",
  10: "b"
}

const keysSorted = Object.keys(myObject).sort(function(a, b) {
      return myObject[a].localeCompare(myObject[b])
    });
    console.log(keysSorted);

const sortedObj={};
keysSorted.forEach(key)={
//convert key to string because in JS,Object which has keys as number type are automatically sorted in ascending//
sortedObj[' '+key] = myObject[key];
})
console.log(sortedObj);
```

Comment: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '['`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. It is (modified version of [Pranav C Balan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40458816/1772898)), gives both key and value.

```js
var myObject = {
        2: "a",
        3: "e",
        4: "h",
        5: "g",
        6: "d",
        7: "i",
        8: "c",
        9: "f",
        10: "b"
    }

keysSorted = Object.entries(myObject).sort(function (a, b) {
    return a[1].localeCompare(b[1]);
});
console.log(keysSorted);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var myObject = {
  2: "a",
  3: "e",
  4: "h",
  5: "g",
  6: "d",
  7: "i",
  8: "c",
  9: "f",
  10: "b"
}

keysSorted = Object.keys(myObject).sort(function(a, b) {
  return myObject[a] < myObject[b] ? -1 : 1
});
console.log(keysSorted);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the only correct and complete answer..

```js
const myObject = {
  2: "a",
  3: "e",
  4: "h",
  5: "g",
  6: "d",
  7: "i",
  8: "c",
  9: "f",
  10: "b"
}

const keysSorted = Object.keys(myObject).sort(function(a, b) {
    return myObject[a].localeCompare(myObject[b])
});
console.log(keysSorted);


const sortedObj={};
keysSorted.forEach(function(key) {
    // Convert key to string because in JS, objects with keys as numbers are automatically sorted in ascending order
    sortedObj['' + key] = myObject[key];
});
console.log(sortedObj);
```