# Converting numbers to their corresponding letters

Tags: javascript

```
function numObj(s){
  var emptyObj = {};
    s.forEach(function(num) {
      emptyObj[num] = String.fromCharCode(num);
   }); 
  return emptyObj;
}
console.log(numObj([118,117,120]));
```

I am writing this function to convert the int to its corresponding char in alphabet. However, 
I am expecting as an output `{'118': 'v', '117': 'u', '120': 'x' }`, but when I ran the code I get: `{ '117': 'u', '118': 'v', '120': 'x' }` . Does anyone have any explanation why does the function change the order of the input?

Comment: There is no guaranteed order of properties in an object.

Comment: Unless, of course, that Object is an `instanceof Array`.

Comment: @PHPglue well even then the ordering is really only guaranteed by code that iterates in numeric order.

Comment: @PHPglue That's not really true. `for (var index in array)` isn't guaranteed to iterate in numeric order.

Comment: Yeah, with a for in loop. Just use a regular for loop.

Comment: Related [How to sort single object alphabetically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40458755/how-to-sort-single-object-alphabetically/)

Comment: I have used for loop, it gave me the same result

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/40459373/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Does JavaScript Guarantee Object Property Order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order) , [Nailing object property order](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/nailing-object-property-order)

Use `Map()`

```js
function numObj(s){
  let emptyObj = new Map();
    s.forEach(function(num) {
      emptyObj.set(num, {[num]:String.fromCharCode(num)});
   }); 
  return emptyObj;
}
let obj = numObj([118,117,120]);

for (let [key, value] of obj.entries()) {
  console.log(key, value)
}
```

or `Array()` to store objects

```js
function numObj(s){
  let emptyObj = Array.from({length:s.length});
    s.forEach(function(num, i) {
      emptyObj[i] = {[num]:String.fromCharCode(num)};
   }); 
  return emptyObj;
}
let obj = numObj([118,117,120]);

for (let [key, value] of obj.entries()) {
  console.log(key, value)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning it as property of an object(even dynamic properties). Hence JS is sorting it internally. Instead I would suggest you to use JS array and its push function.

Answer (score 0):

You can't guarantee the order of the properties on a JavaScript object. Aside from `Map()` and using an Array, if you wanted this object to know about the original order of the inputted array of character codes, you could add an `order` property. By creating a reference of the intended order on the object, you can use it when doing something like printing out the values.

```js
function numObj(s){
  var emptyObj = {};
  emptyObj.order = [];
  s.forEach(function(num) {
    emptyObj[num] = String.fromCharCode(num);
    emptyObj.order.push(num);
  });

  return emptyObj;
}

var obj = numObj([118,117,120]);

obj.order.forEach(function(i){
  console.log(i + " : " + obj[i]);
});
```